# Remove git repository from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I added a git repository to my project and then I hit **Team > Disconnect**. How do I remove this repository completely? I'm trying to set up a new git repository on my project, but I keep getting an error message.

Comment: Open the Git Perspective and remove the repository from there. You can have git repositories that don't correspond to projects.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Whenever I do that i get an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository config file /path/to/directory/workspace/Backend/.git/config invalid Cannot read file /path/to/directory/workspace/Backend/.git/config

Comment: you probably removed the repository by hand; create a simple git repo with `git init` at that location so that you can remove it from Eclipse, then remove it manually (bvut IIRC Eclipse also gives you an option to remove the repository files).

Comment: @TassosBassoukos so i cd into my project and did git init...how do I remove it manually from eclipse? (sorry I'm really new to Eclipse)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Eclipse go to `Window > Show View -> Other...` Then select `Git > Git Repositories`. A view with all your Git repositories should now be visible. Right-click on the repository you want to remove and select `Delete repository`.
Eclipse will now ask for a confirmation and give you the option to remove all repository data.

In Eclipse Neon you can also delete a repository by hand (via the OS). In that case the repository will simply disappear in the Eclipse Git Repositories view. This is not recommended for older Eclipse versions!

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to remove the repository from the Eclipse but not want to delete the data from your computer, follow these steps :

1. First switch to ***Git*** perspective (***Window - > Open Perspective -> Other -> Search for Git***)
2. In the ***Git Repositories*** section, right click your repository and select ***Remove Repository from View***. This will prompt you to confirm if you want to remove the projects that are imported in Eclipse from this repository. Click ***Yes*** and you are done.